# Excel - Index Match with Large function: Show duplicate values?

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I am using the following array forumla:

```
=INDEX('Opp Data'!$H:$H,MATCH(1,('Opp Data'!$G$1:$G$1000=$A$10)*('Opp Data'!$K$1:$K$1000=LARGE(IF('Opp Data'!$G$1:$G$1000=$A$10,'Opp Data'!$K$1:$K$1000),6)),0))
```

The formula is designed to look up my Opp Data sheet which is laid out like the below:

```
Column H         Column G          Column K
Client A         Aerospace         £200
Client B         Rail              £150
Client C         Aerospace         £100
```

The formula should check which clients have the highest spend and using Large function, on each row i can set my 1st, 2nd and 3rd largest values etc.

I am also checking my cell A10 which has the word 'Aerospace' in it.
The formula should only return those client names that have aerospace corresponding to them in column g.

My end result should look like this.

```
Client A
Client C
```

This works fine, however if we had two clients with the same value in column k like so:

```
Column H         Column G          Column K
Client A         Aerospace         £200
Client B         Rail              £150
Client C         Aerospace         £100
Client D         Aerospace         £100
```

Then client D is not listed and my formula reproduces client c twice.

Please can someone show me how i can get duplicate values (NOT duplicate client names!) to show?

Am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: In which cell do you start the formula?  The reason is it is possible by adding a countif() in the equation.  but to give the equation modification I would need to now the first cell address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Countif() into the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Opp Data'!$H:$H,MATCH(1,('Opp Data'!$G$1:$G$1000=$A$10)*('Opp Data'!$K$1:$K$1000=LARGE(IF('Opp Data'!$G$1:$G$1000=$A$10,'Opp Data'!$K$1:$K$1000),ROW(1:1))*(COUNTIF($C$10:$C10,'Opp Data'!$H$1:$H$1000)=0)),0)),"")
```

The count if would grow as it is dragged down, see what is absolute and what is relative.

I also added ROW(1:1), this then is dynamic, as it is dragged down it changes from 1 to 2 to 3 and so forth, so the `k` in the Large will adjust automatically.

Being an Array Formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode.  When done correctly Excel will automatically put `{}` around the formula to denote an array formula.

See photo for reference on cell address.

[image]

---

If you add the values in order, then you can use the AGGREGATE() formula for a non CSE Array.

To get the values:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,'Opp Data'!$K$1:$K$1000/('Opp Data'!$G$1:$G$1000=$A$10),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then using that in another column that refers to the column of numbers:

```
=IF(D11="","",INDEX('Opp Data'!$H$1:$H$1000,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$1000)/(('Opp Data'!$G$1:$G$4=$A$10)*('Opp Data'!$K$1:$K$4=Sheet12!D11)),COUNTIF($D$11:$D11,D11))))
```

These are non Ctrl-Shift-Enter array formula, so enter them as normal formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well.  I would be interested in a more elegant solution, but my workaround has been to add an extra column to modify column K to make the values unique, and have my Large function reference that column instead of K.  Something like:

```
=$K2 + row()/10000000
```

Should make unique values for each row which you could reference in your array function.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but when you say this makes the values unique, do you mean this alters the values as i need these to be 100% accurate and can't change then :(

Comment: You wouldn't alter column K, and link anything that needed to be totally accurate to column K, just use the new column to un-duplicate values for the large formula.